# Create a new table from an existing one on a criteria in R

Tags: r, merge, data-cleaning

I've done a self-paced reading experiment in which 151 participants read 112 sentences divided into three lists and I'm having some problems cleaning the data in R. I'm not a programmer so I'm kind of struggling with all this!

I've got the results file which looks something like this:

```
results

part item word n.word rt
51  106 *   1   382
51  106 El  2   286
51  106 asistente   3   327
51  106 del 4   344
51  106 carnicero   5   394
51  106 que 6   274
51  106 abapl’a 7   2327
51  106 el  8   1104
51  106 sabor   9   409
51  106 del 10  360
51  106 pollo   11  1605
51  106 envipi— 12  256
51  106 un  13  4573
51  106 libro   14  660
51  106 *.  15  519
```

Part=participant; item=sentences; n.word=number of word; rt=reading times.

In the results file, I have the reading times of every word of every sentence read by every participant. Every participant read more or less 40 sentences. My problem is that I am interested in the reading times of specific words, such as the main verb or the last word of each sentence. But as every sentence is a bit different, the main verb is not always in the same position for each sentence. So I've done another table with the position of the words I'm interested in every sentence.

```
rules

item v1 v2 n1 n2
 106 12  7  3  5
 107 11  8  3  6
 108 11  8  3  6
```

item=sentence; v1=main verb; v2=secondary verb; n1=first noun; n2=second noun.
So this should be read: For sentence 106, the main verb is the word number 12, the secondary verb is the word number 7 and so on.

I want to have a final table that looks like this:

```
results2

part item  v1   v2  n1  n2
51    106 256 2327 327 394
51    107 ...
52    106 ...
```

Does anyone know how to do this? It's kind of a from long to wide problem but with a more complex scenario.
If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!!

Comment: it seems you are doing some data merging `merge(transform(reshape(rules,list(2:ncol(rules)), dir="long", idvar = "item"), n.word = v1),results)[c("item","n.word","rt")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code, which joins your `results` data to a reshaped `rules` data, and then reshapes the result into a wider form.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

inner_join(select(results, -word),
  pivot_longer(rules, -item), c("item", "n.word"="value")) %>%
  select(-n.word) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=rt) %>%
  select(part, item, v1, v2, n1, n2)

# A tibble: 1 x 6
#   part  item    v1    v2    n1    n2
#  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    51   106   256  2327   327   394
```

---

**Data**:

```
results <-  structure(list(part = c(51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 
51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L), item = c(106L, 106L, 106L, 
106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 106L, 
106L), word = c("*", "El", "asistente", "del", "carnicero", "que", 
"abapl’a", "el", "sabor", "del", "pollo", "envipi—", "un", "libro", 
"*."), n.word = 1:15, rt = c(382L, 286L, 327L, 344L, 394L, 274L, 
2327L, 1104L, 409L, 360L, 1605L, 256L, 4573L, 660L, 519L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))

rules <- structure(list(item = 106:108, v1 = c(12L, 11L, 11L), v2 = c(7L, 
8L, 8L), n1 = c(3L, 3L, 3L), n2 = c(5L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks, Edward! This worked perfectly! I've been dealing with this for three days so you are my favorite person at the moment!